# CSI Driver: FSGroup mentioned in POD spec is not accessible from NodePublish volume

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-volume

I am using

```
 volumeMountGroup := req.GetVolumeCapability().GetMount().GetVolumeMountGroup()
 klog.V(2).Infof("-NodePublishVolume-: volumeMountGroup: %v",volumeMountGroup)
```

in my CSI NodePublishVolume method to access FSGroup mentioned in pod spec.

My Pod spec is as follows

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cos-csi-app-s3fs
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app-frontend
      image: rabbitmq
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/data"
        name: cos-csi-volume
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsGroup: 2000
    runAsUser: 2000
  volumes:
    - name: cos-csi-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
```

In the logs , empty value is printed.

```
I0321 08:42:05.845519       1 nodeserver.go:144] -NodePublishVolume-: volumeMountGroup:
```

I expected "2000". Have I missed something or is my understanding about the concept wrong.
I have added necessary capability to driver

```
 csi.NodeServiceCapability_RPC_VOLUME_MOUNT_GROUP,
```